# Xparse macro with optional parameter breaks value for PGF foreach

Tags: macros, loops, foreach, optional-arguments, xparse

I write a document class and want to execute something a certain number of times, depending on a user-defined quantity. So I thought I'd use a `foreach` loop from PGF together with accessor macros:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{xparse,etoolbox,pgffor}

\makeatletter
\csdef{my@test}{3}

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\val}{m g}{%
  \csname #1@#2\endcsname%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  Testing direct: \csname my@test\endcsname

  Testing macro: \val{my}{test}

  \foreach \i in {1,...,\csname my@test\endcsname}{a}

  \foreach \i in {1,...,\val{my}{test}}{a}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, using `val` breaks `foreach`:

[image]

with error message `Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)` (several times).

Funny: if I use parameter specification `{m m}` instead of `{m g}`, the problem goes away.

It is feasible to not use the macro inside the class definition -- I do need the optional parameter, though -- but what is going on here?

#### Background

Users can create a list of `X`s by using a macro of the form

```
\addX{group}{name}{key1=val1,key2=val2,..}
```

This macro is implemented with `xparse` and `keyval`. It stores the information in macros of the form `\X@group@name@key`. In order to hide this from users, I provide accessor macros like `val` above. There are also macros and environments that utilise the created list directly, one of which would contain a loop as defined above, repeating stuff (for every `X`) depending on user-provided values.

The last parameter of `val` is to be optional so that a default value can be returned if the user provides no key (which would be the value I suppose will be requested most often).

Comment: Are you really sure you want an optional final argument in braces? I'd consider this bad syntax.

Comment: @egreg That depends on your background, I guess. (La)TeX is the only language I know that uses different delimiters for optional arguments, and its treatment of parameters in general is ... baffling. So yea, by LaTeX standards this is weird syntax, however I intend my class to be used by people with minimal if any LaTeX skills so I try to keep LaTeX idiosyncrasies hidden as much as possible.

Comment: @egreg: My point is that my target group (RPG GMs) are unlikely to be aware of these conventions and probably don't want to be. (Besides, having optional parameters *before* the mandatory ones strikes me as an extremely unfortunate design decision, usage-wise. But that's a discussion for somewhere else.)

Comment: Is the user supposed to type `\foreach\i in {1,...,\val{my}{test}}{...}`? I don't think so.

Comment: @egreg No, but they are supposed to be able to use `\val` in other contexts. If possible, I'd like both usage cases to work for my and their convenience; if that's not possible, I'll choose theirs.

Comment: Given your update, why not make all three arguments mandatory.  In that context you could write `\val{arg1}{}` when you want to treat the second argument as optional.  `xparse` allows you to test for an empty argument.  And, I believe this will preserve expandability.

Comment: @A.Ellett: That's certainly a possibilty and probably a good compromise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be an expandability issue.  It seems that `xparse`'s manner of defining functions with optional arguments is preventing `\foreach` from seeing the final value in its domain.  In particular, `\foreach` cannot fully expand the value of your macro because `xparse` method for creating `g` type arguments prevents full expansion.

Even if the optional argument precedes the mandatory argument, you run into a similar error:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{xparse,etoolbox,pgffor}

\makeatletter
\csdef{my@test}{3}

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\val}{o m}{%
  \csname #1@#2\endcsname%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

  Testing direct: \csname my@test\endcsname

  Testing macro: \val[my]{test}

  \foreach \i in {1,...,\csname my@test\endcsname}{a}

  \foreach \i in {1,...,\val[my]{test} }{a}

\end{document}
```

In the documentation for `xparse` you can create fully expandable functions with optional arguments, but various restrictions apply:

- The optional argument may not be of type `g`
- The last argument may not be an optional argument.

You can write the following

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{xparse,etoolbox,pgffor}

\makeatletter
\csdef{my@test}{3}

\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\val}{o m}{%
  \csname #1@#2\endcsname%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

  Testing direct: \csname my@test\endcsname

  Testing macro: \val[my]{test}

  \foreach \i in {1,...,\csname my@test\endcsname}{a}

  \foreach \i in {1,...,\val[my]{test} }{a}

\end{document}
```

Doing a bit of gimmickry you can get a partial glance of what's happening expansion-wise

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{xparse,etoolbox,pgffor}

\makeatletter
\csdef{my@test}{3}

%% an expandable version of your macro
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\eval}{o m}{%
  \csname #1@#2\endcsname%
}

%% a non-expandable version of your macro
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\val}{o m}{%
  \csname #1@#2\endcsname%
}
\makeatother
\setlength{\parskip}{2ex}
\begin{document}


 \makebox[1in][r]{Full expanded}: 
    \begin{minipage}[t]{3in}\ttfamily
      \detokenize\expandafter{\romannumeral-`G\eval[my]{test}}
    \end{minipage}

  \makebox[1in][r]{Expanded once}: 
    \begin{minipage}[t]{3in}\ttfamily
      \detokenize\expandafter{\eval[my]{test}}
    \end{minipage}

  \makebox[1in][r]{Not fully expandable}:
    \begin{minipage}[t]{3in}\ttfamily
      \detokenize\expandafter{\romannumeral-`G\val[my]{test}}
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Perhaps if you clarify how this macro is to behave, we can come up with a solution that better meets your needs.

**UPDATE**

You could make both your arguments mandatory, but test whether the second argument has been passed an empty argument.

Here's the code:

```
\csdef{my@default}{5}

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\eval}{ mm }{%%
  \expandafter\ifx\expandafter\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax
    \csname #1@default\endcsname
  \else
    \csname #1@#2\endcsname
  \fi
}
```

Then you can write something like

```
  \foreach \i in {1,...,\eval{my}{}}{D}

  \foreach \i in {1,...,\eval{my}{test}}{c}
```

I should point out, though, that `\eval{my}{ }` will not test true for an empty argument.

Comment: Thank you for this elaborate explanation! Too bad that there is no `\expandall` with which we could wrap problematic code (or is there?). It seems as if I can not implement what I want, so I have to rethink my approach or deal with the restrictions of `val` as is. (For background, see my expanded question.)

Comment: @Raphael Regarding `\expandall`, that's *sort of* what `\romannumeral` is doing above.  But you can't force expansion of unexpandable content.  LaTeX (TeX) processes material from left to right.  A macro with optional arguments requires LaTeX to know what's to the right of the current token before expansion of the current token:  so, this irreparably breaks expansion.

Comment: Thanks! It think `xparse` offers commands for trimming whitespace off arguments and `xifthen` can be used to check for emptiness; or would that break expandability again? (Quick tests make it seem so.)